# Alfresco: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: alfresco, permgen

I installed Alfresco Community 4.2.0c (manual install) with these Tomcat settings in `startup.sh`:

> CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=900m -XX:NewSize=512m -server -Dalfresco.home=/home/aegif/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"

On Oracle jdk1.7.0_15, Linux 2.6.18, CentOS 5.8.
When I launch `startup.sh`, Alfresco starts running, but a minute after the `Alfresco started` message, I get:

```
Apr 15, 2013 7:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

How can I get this error even though `MaxPermSize=900m` which is already a huge value?
By the way, I get the same exception with other MaxPermSize values like 256m or 700m.

Hint: The log says:

```
maximum heap size 247.500MB
WARNING - maximum heap size 247.500MB is less than recommended 512MB
```

Even though `startup.sh` has `-Xmx1024m`.

Is my CATALINA_OPTS wrong?

Comment: Would the NewSize option be the one it's complaining about?

Comment: @NickW: Same error message and same numbers with NewSize=512m

Comment: Do you have a JAVA_OPTS option, or a setenv.sh file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that its taking the CATALINA_OPTS value from somewhere else, have a look at catalina.sh also try to put/define these settings in catalina.sh instead of startup.sh.

Comment: Moving the settings from startup.sh to catalina.sh worked! (always at the beginning of the file, after the first line, by the way)